# Mobilenum validation is not working in aspx

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have been added mobile number validation in my aspx page

Here is my code:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="label7" runat="server" Text="Mobile Number"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="10"
            OnClientClick="return Validatemobilenum();"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
```

script:

```
function Validatemobilenum() {
        var phone = document.getElementById("<%=Textmobilenum.ClientID%>");
        var RE = /^[\d\.\-]+$/;
        if (phone.value != "") {
            if (!RE.test(phone.value)) {
                alert("You have entered an invalid phone number");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {

            alert("please Enter mobile number");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

When i run the above code,

It works even if i insert characters for mobile number. That is the above script is not working.

May i know, what is my mistake?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: It's because you are calling the method in OnClientClick instead on this you need either onkeyup or onkeydown.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your comment?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your comment? Thanks

Comment: `<asp:TextBox ID="Textmobilenum" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="10" onkeypress="return Validatemobilenum();"></asp:TextBox>`. As i said before add a onkeypress property instead on OnClientClick and with that in the function you need to track keyboard events and restrict user to input only number and nothing else.

Comment: I don't want onkeyup and onkeydown.. may i know , is there possible to add onclientclick?

Comment: I mean.. after enter invalid characters for mobile number.. then only it shows error message..

Comment: OnClientClick raises event when you click some where on fly it has nothing to with what you are looking for you need to block alphabet or special character for that you need to target keyboard events.

Comment: @Rani: I have added an answer for `onClientClick` have a look below

Comment: @suprabhat:  OK.. but onkeypress event raised quickly when enter the curser in mobilenum text box

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal: is the code, working on `onkeypress` ?

Comment: @coder: I haven't tried it out but keyboard event are the only way that meets op requirement to allow only number. I order to make it work i need to right to down and i don't have ample amount to time to do it.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal: I tried that, but i guess its not working.

Comment: @coder: you need toi pass event as arguement and get event.which or keycode and comapre it with ascii and then allow or return false. hope this make some sense.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal: i used OnClientClick="javascript:return Validate()" .. its too not working..

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal: yes, got it that..thanks

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1**

You need to write your code on [`Onblur`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp) attribute, like below:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Textmobilenum" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="10" onblur="return Validatemobilenum()"></asp:TextBox>
```

**SOLUTION 2**

**UPDATE**

If you want to check that function on `OnClientClick` event, you need to add a `Button` for that, Like below

```
<asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" OnClientClick="return Validatemobilenum()" Width="100" Text="Validate" />
```

And your js function

```
function Validatemobilenum() {
        var phone = document.getElementById("<%=Textmobilenum.ClientID%>");
        var RE = /^[\d\.\-]+$/;
        if (phone.value != "") {
            if (!RE.test(phone.value)) {
                alert("You have entered an invalid phone number");
                return false;
            }
            alert('Correct mobile number entered');
        }
        else {

            alert("please Enter mobile number");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**NOTE**:- Not sure about your regular  expression

Comment: Its not button.. i have been created form and it contains mobile number text box..

Comment: then check my first answer, before update. Its working.

Comment: i need only onclientclick.. i used once upon a time.. now its not working..thanks

Comment: you cannot add `onClientclick` on textbox, you need some click event to fire that and textbox can never do that. Anyways, I have provided you 2 solutions which were working. Thanks.!